# how to connect an android device to a printer?

Tags: api, printing, android

is there an android api that would connect an android device to a printer?
what are the possible ways to connect to a printer in android?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using USB android.hardware.usb package. USBManager class and further.
I dont know much.
I myself am learning about it.
Hope you try out.
Tc

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to print to a big desktop printer or a receipt printer?

If you're looking for a receipt printer, Star Micronics has an Android SDK that you can freely download here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx.

It covers USB, ethernet, and bluetooth printing. If you want to use USB, these printers can be connected directly to tablets supporting that port. Your tablet needs to have Android V3.1 or higher for direct USB connection with a printer.

This SDK has a really nice sample app that lets you test and customize a lot of printer functions to see them in action. Each function is documented in the source code. The commands and their parameters are also available in the app itself as a quick on screen reference which is convenient. On top of all that, it's well documented.